# Correlation between previous year growth and monthly climate variable

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation, climate

I want to calculate Pearsons correlation coeff. between growth variable (tree-ring measurements) and monthly climate variable (e.g. monthly average temperatures) for a period of 100 years.
In that sense, I want to calculate for a 24-month period (current year of tree ring formation AND prior year to tree ring formation).

How do I correlate previous year to ring formation growth with climate variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have data for $t=1, \dots, T$ years. Let's denote the yearly growth variable by $X_t$. Denote the monthly climate data by $Y_{t,m}$ where $m$ is the month corresponding to year $t$ so that $m=1, \dots, 12$. Now, you want to compute the correlation between last year's growth and the current years climate data. You do this by lagging the growth variable by 1 and then running correlations with the climate variables. That is, you will have 12 series like $((X_{0},Y_{1,m}),(X_{1},Y_{2,m}), \dots)$ for each $m$. Now simply compute the correlation for each of these.